# Get Nhibernate entity and complete it from a web service

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

let's say that i have an order system.
each "Order" references a "Customer" Object.
when i fill the orders list in Data Access Layer, the customer object should be brought from
a Customer Web Service "WCF".
so i didn't map the Customer property in the Order mapping class,

```
        Id(o => o.OrderID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        //References(o => o.Customer).Not.Nullable().Column("CustomerID");
        HasMany(o => o.Details).KeyColumn("OrderID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        Map(c => c.CustomerID).Not.Nullable();
```

and asked the nhibernate session to get me the orders list.
and tried to loop on every order in the list to fill it's customer property,
doe's any body have a good idea for this ????

```
 IList<Order> lst = Session.CreateCriteria<Order>().List<Order>();
 foreach (Order order in lst)
                order.Customer = serviceProxy.GetCustomerByID(order.CustomerID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're saying that you hit your WCF, for Order list of 50, 50 times. Not so good.

You should do this:

```
   var customers = serviceProxy.GetCustomersForIDs(lst.Select(x => x.CustomerID).Distinct()); //one hit to WCF

   foreach(var order in lst)
        order.Customer = customers.Single(x => x.ID == order.CustomerID);
```

That is for performance vise.

The other thing that you can do and be fancy (and not so performace oriented, but exactly the same performace as your sample):

modify property Customer as this:

```
       private customer;
       public virtual Customer
       {
            get
            {
                 if(customer == null)
                     customer = serviceProxy.GetCustomerByID(this.CustomerID);
                 return customer;
            }
        }
```

Where your order should have a reference to serviceProxy.

Comment: sorry for being late,
Dmonlord, thanks for the reply, the first solution looks nice,
but the other solution, suggests that the Model should have a reference to a service proxy, which violate the enterprise application patterns IMHO: that imply Model should be persistent-ignorant.

am i right ?

Comment: Well, I'd go for the first solution, too. I don't like fancy stuff like ActiveRecord pattern which can shoot you in the leg when the application becomes more complex. I stay on service/repository pattern and simple (more or less only properties) domain model. I don't care if some people say that that is not a real domain driven design.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to do this transparently, try implementing a custom tuplizer (and associated things). Take a look at [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363571/Remote-Lazy-Loading-in-Hibernate), it implements a remote lazy loader for Java Hibernate, however the general concepts apply equally to NHibernate since it has the same overall design (tuplizers, lazy initializers, proxy factory, etc).